# Fill a char* in another function using malloc in c/c++

Tags: c++, c, malloc, esp8266

I'm codding for Arduino (ESP8266), and have to read a string from a file, to use it. I don't know how long is that file, so I have to create a `char*` and pass it to the `readConf` function so that `malloc` decides for the memory size.

```
void readConf(char path[], char **buff){
    SPIFFS.begin();
    if (SPIFFS.exists(path))
    {
        File file = SPIFFS.open(path, "r");
        int size = file.size();
        Serial.print("File size: ");
        Serial.println(size);
        char *bu;
        bu = (char*) malloc((size+1) * sizeof(char));
        file.read((uint8_t*) bu, size);
        bu[size] = '\0';
        Serial.print("Data: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            Serial.print(bu[i]);
        Serial.println("");
        //Everything is OK. It is printed correctly.
        buff = &bu; //!This is the problem!
        file.close();
    }
    SPIFFS.end();
}

#define file_path "/file"
void setup(){
    
    if(WiFi.getMode() != WIFI_STA)
        WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
    
    char* username;
    readConf(file_path, &username);
    char* password;
    readConf(file_path, &password);
    /*The same with password. */
    WiFi.begin(username, password);
    
    Serial.print("username: ");
    Serial.println(username); //Here I sometimes get Exception, and sometimes prints non-sense characters
    free(username); //My memory is limited. I'm doing all this stuff for this line!
    //...
}
```

I also searched a lot in StackOverflow and other sites, also used `char *`, `char **`, filling the pointer directly in the `readConf` function, and a lot more but non of them worked. How should I deal with it? Can I do it at all?

**NOTE**: I should not use String class.

Comment: Try `*buff = bu` instead. Or if you're really programming in C++ use *actual* references instead of pointers to emulate references.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I used to get a lot of hardware exceptions, as a result, Arduino would restart again and again. I have to use it this way.

Comment: By the way, why are you now using the Arduino standard `String` class for your strings?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Hardware exceptions:)) I had the same error as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60966280/esp8266-repeatedly-throws-exception0, so as https://stackoverflow.com/a/60969009/9691976 says: `This error pattern is typical for the String class.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function parameter `buff` is a local variable of the function

```
void readConf(char path[], char **buff){
```

So changing it within the function

```
buff = &bu; //!This is the problem!
```

has neither effect on the variable `password` declared in the function `setup`

```
char* password;
readConf(file_path, &password);
```

You need to write

```
*buff = bu;
```

That is you need in the function `readConf` to change the value of the pointer `password` declared in the function `setup`

So you passed the pointer to the function `readConf` by reference through a pointer to it

```
readConf(file_path, &password);
```

Now to get a direct access to the original pointer `password` you need to dereference the parameter `buff` that was initialized by the expression `&password`.

Comment: Would you please explain more? Why mine is wrong and the second one you wrote is OK?

Comment: @MohammadKholghi See my appended answer.

Answer (score 1):

This function will return size of file in bytes.

```
#include <fstream>

std::ifstream::pos_type filesize(const char* filename)
{
    std::ifstream in(filename, std::ifstream::ate | std::ifstream::binary);
    return in.tellg(); 
}
```

char* buff; - that is pointer to char array. Not char** buff;

Comment: it is not a Question about a computer file system

Comment: Thanks a lot, but the real problem is not about the file size. It's about the pointers.

Comment: I think i clarify about pointer to shar array too.